# Python: very basic help on a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I've searched everywhere for an answer to my question, and I still can't figure it out! The answer is probably sooooo simple but I just can't get it, maybe because I'm just getting back into Python...

Anyway, I want to create a while-loop so that until the user enters 'y' or 'n' the question will keep being asked. This is what I have:

```
while True:   # to loop the question
    answer = input("Do you like burgers? ").lower()
    if answer == "y" or "n":
        break
```

I'm honestly so baffed, so I beg for someone's help :)

Comment: `if answer in ("y", "n"):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while True:   # to loop the question
    answer = input("Do you like burgers? ").lower()
    if answer == "y" or answer == "n":
        break
```

Comment: If you wonder why this works: in Python, strings have a truth value true. A non-empty string is always true: `bool("foo") == True`, so your code will always break because of `... or "n"` which corresponds to `... or True`.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is wrong. Also if you are using Python 2.x you should use `raw_input` (otherwise you would need to type `"y"` instead of `y`, for example):

```
while True:   # to loop the question
    answer = raw_input("Do you like burgers? ").lower()
    if answer == "y" or answer == "n":
        break
```